# Facing error while updating size of table-field in sql server 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server 2010 that contains bulk amount of data. i am facing error while updating the siz of one of the field in one of table.

**`code`**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] (
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     INT             NULL,
    [Juz_ID]                       INT             NULL,
    [Surah_ID]                     INT             NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_Description]             NVARCHAR (3900) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_No]                      INT             NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fkey2] FOREIGN KEY ([Translation_Laanguage_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Translation_Language] ([TransLation_Language_ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fkey0] FOREIGN KEY ([Juz_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Juz] ([Juz_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [fkey1] FOREIGN KEY ([Surah_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Surah] ([Surah_ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

when i try to change the size of `[Ayat_Description]` from 3900 to 5000, it shows random error. how to fix it ?

Comment: If i am not mistaken there's no SQL Server 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]`
Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.

You will need to enter either 4000 or max, in case you need to store more than 4000 characters